# ui:repeat inside a ui:repeat and LazyInitException

Tags: java, exception, jsf, transactional

I'm currently experiencing a LazyInitException with a page containing code like the following:

```
<h:form>
<ui:repeat value="#{searchBean.storiesByTag}" var="iStory">
<ui:repeat value="{iStory.tags}"var="iTag">      
<!-- Lazy init exception here -->
#{iTag.content}
</ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

`storiesByTag()` is a bean method that retrieves a `List` of stories. The second `ui:repeat` is supposed to then take each tag and display it's content. All fetching is lazy by default to avoid loading more objects than is necessary.

I'm still fuzzy on this but, from what I understand, this can happen because an `EntityManager` is closed (exit from `@Transactional` cloud) during a request or a `Collection` is being accessed.

Spring's `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` from Spring has been added to the project but I'm not sure if it's doing it's job correctly. Any suggestions for testing this are welcome.

Since I assume the `Collection` is the problem here I'd like to know what would be a good solution. Should I modify a DAO method with a `fetch join`? Or should I take the hacky route by using `<f:view beforePhaseListener=...>` to trigger a method inside a bean and get some fresh Tag objects from the database?

Edit: For Bozho:

**web.xml**:

```
<!-- Open EM in View Filter -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- End -->
```

For Roman:

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

Comment: how is your `OpenEntityManagerInView` configured? Are you doing redirect or forward to the view?

Comment: OpenEntityManagerInView is defined as a filter in web.xml (see above). Redirection is being used.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your entity manager factory?

From OpenEntityManagerInView docs:

> Looks up the EntityManagerFactory in Spring's root web application context. Supports a "entityManagerFactoryBeanName" filter init-param in web.xml; the default bean name is "entityManagerFactory".

If you specified the name different from "entityManagerFactory" then the filter doesn't see your factory.

Comment: It's the standard "entityManagerFactory" (see above). Useful bit of info though :)