# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and testing the presence of an EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jpa

I posted a question a few days ago mentionning Spring's OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:
[ui:repeat inside a ui:repeat and LazyInitException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385858/uirepeat-inside-a-uirepeat-and-lazyinitexception)

What I'd like to know is of a way to test if an EntityManager is available during a request. What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: "how to test for the presence of an EntityManager" - what do you mean?

Comment: I don't get the question. Can you make it obvious for me? :)

Comment: I'm simply looking for a way to find out if OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter is doing it's job properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear where exactly you intend to test it, but in general just checking if the following doesn't throw an exception (e.g. [`PersistenceException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html)) ought to be a sufficient hint.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(name);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

The `name` is obviously the persistence unit name as definied in the `/META-INF/persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

My team has given up trying to get OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter to work for the moment because of time constraints and we've switched FetchTypes to eager. It might not be initializing properly or is incompatible with JSF 1.2. If anyone reading this comes accross a solution please let me know.